# Is it possible to send FCM to various tokens from cloud functions for specific operating OS?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send FCM to various tokens saved in the firestore document as an array with the use of firebase cloud functions. Also is it possible to send the FCM to platform-specific options in the payload. I tried a lot of examples and none worked for me. I attached the code for reference.

Tokens in firestore document:
[image]

```
...
let tokens2 = [];
await admin.firestore().doc(`Users/${uid}`).get().then(queryResult => {
    let tokensResult = queryResult.data().tokens;
    tokens2 = tokensResult;
  });

    let message = {
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: content
      },
      data: {
        channel_id: "some_channel"
      },
      android: {
        notification: {
          notificationCount: 1
        }
      },
      apns: {
        payload: {
          aps: {
            badge: 42,
            sound: "default"
          }
        }
      },
      token: [tokens2]
    };

    let response = await admin.messaging().send(message).catch(e => console.log(e));;
    console.log(response);
```

the last error on my function console:
[image]

I also tried with sendToDevice and send multicast but no lucky

any help is welcome :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a notification to specific platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955979/how-to-send-a-notification-to-specific-platform)

Comment: thank you Farid for your answer, but that post specifically talk about how to separate platforms (I already did this), the questions is, is possible to do specific platform for various tokens at the same time? thank you again, regards

Comment: Hey @RafaelZablah, have you found a solution? Did you check this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524448/cloud-functions-for-firebase-send-fcm-message-to-multiple-tokens/50524673?